# chopping blocks

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

When I try to destroy any type of minecraft block it doesn't do anything. I click on it and hold but niether right or left click works. I've tried creative and survival but yet no luck. What is wrong with it?

Comment: Does your arm/tool show the swinging/hitting animation, or does simply nothing happen?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the controls, or check your mouse/keypad is working.